# Qt: display tooltip on LineEdit widget that is mapped to AbstractListModel

Tags: python, qt, tooltip, pyqt5

### Situation

Below is a Qt example that contains an `AbstractListModel` and two display widgets that are linked to this model (a `ListView` and a `LineEdit`):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, data_values, tooltips, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data_values = data_values
        self.tooltips = tooltips


    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.data_values)


    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if (role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
            return self.data_values[index.row()]
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            return self.tooltips[index.row()]


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        data_values = ['apple', 'pumpkin', 'orange']
        tooltips = [
            "Don't accept when offered by evil queen in disguise.",
            "Excellent halloween decoration.",
            "Good source of Vitamin C.",
        ]
        self.list_model = ListModel(data_values, tooltips)

        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.line_edit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.list_view = QtWidgets.QListView(parent=self)
        self.list_view.setModel(self.list_model)
        self.list_view.setCurrentIndex(self.list_model.index(0))

        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper(parent=self)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.list_model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.line_edit, 0)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

        self.list_view.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(self.mapper.setCurrentModelIndex)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.list_view, 0)
        layout.insertSpacing(1, 40)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit, 2)
        self.setLayout(layout)


qt_application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
qt_application.exec_()
```

I have configured the `data` method of the `AbstractListModel` to supply tooltip texts to linked widgets. A tooltip indeed appears when the mouse cursor is placed over an item in the `ListView`. However no tooltip appears when the mouse cursor is placed over the `LineEdit`.

[image]

### Problem

I would like for the `LineEdit` to display a tooltip with the text provided by the linked `AbstractListModel`. Is there any way at all to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this with `QDataWidgetMapper`. `QDataWidgetMapper` always uses the `Qt::EditRole` value of the model. One could suggest to use the overloaded version of [`addMapping`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html#addMapping-1) and a `TableModel` with one column (`section`) for displaying and one for the tooltip, but this is not possible, because `QDataWidgetMapper` only allows you to implement [one-to-one mapping](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html#addMapping):

> If the widget is already mapped to a section, the old mapping will be
>   replaced by the new one.

**Solution**

The easiest solution is to create a slot yourself which you connect to the `currentRowChanged` signal and which sets the tooltip ([`QWidget::setToolTip`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop)) and text ([`QLineEdit::setText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop)) manually.

Comment: Aha, good to know that `QDataWidgetMapper` always uses `Qt::EditRole`. That already explains a lot as to why nothing happens in my example. Thanks.